# Lighttpd - Cannot start, can't bind port, permission denied

Tags: django, lighttpd

I have installed Lighttpd in parallel with Apache (using port 80). But starting lighttpd gives me an error

```
Starting lighttpd: 2013-04-05 15:56:17: (network.c.379) can't bind to port:  81 Permission denied
```

Changes I made in lighttpd.conf:

```
server.port = 81
server.use-ipv6 = "disable"
```

What am I missing here? I am using CentOS 6.3

**netstat -ltp** result:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 localhost:smux              *:*                         LISTEN      1947/snmpd          
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                     *:*                         LISTEN      15673/mysqld        
tcp        0      0 *:57071                     *:*                         LISTEN      1683/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                    *:*                         LISTEN      1665/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 *:ndmp                      *:*                         LISTEN      2473/perl           
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      1959/sshd           
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp               *:*                         LISTEN      1829/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp              *:*                         LISTEN      2362/master         
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                    *:*                         LISTEN      1665/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 *:http                      *:*                         LISTEN      15422/httpd         
tcp        0      0 *:45684                     *:*                         LISTEN      1683/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      1959/sshd           
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp               *:*                         LISTEN      1829/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp              *:*                         LISTEN      2362/master         
tcp        0      0 *:6556                      *:*                         LISTEN      1967/xinetd
```

Comment: are you starting it as root?

Comment: which ouput gives you `netstat -ltp` or `lsof -i4tcp:81`?

Comment: i have added in my question netstat -ltp. thanks!

Comment: **lsof -i4tcp:81** returns empty

Comment: strange, no processes are using that port number, maybe as pointed here, selinux? http://forum.soluslabs.com/showthread.php/1906-Cannot-start-lighttpd seems a system permission problem, try to launch it with `strace` and look for system error there.

Comment: Is there a reason to have both Apache and Lighttpd installed at the same time?

Comment: Apache handles our dynamic pages and Lighttpd handles our media files.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this reference and solves my problem. The issue was due to SELinux blocking lighttpd in using port 81.

[updated link] https://www.visibilityspots.com/selinux.html

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Can you post an updated link if there is one?